# Python Xlsxwriter not overwriting when in constant mode on

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I'm currently using xlsxwriter in constant_mode = True. When I try to overwrite a certain part of the excel write it doesn't work. But when the constant mode is False it work's like a charm. I read also the documentation of the xlsxwriter but I'm hardly to grasp the documentation.

Can someone point me where to start on xlsxwriter manipulation when on constant_mode is True?

Thanks

Sample Code:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx',{'constant_memory': True})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


row_max = 10
col_max = 10

some_data = "World"
for row in range(5, row_max):
    for col in range(5, col_max):
        worksheet.write(row, col, some_data)

some_data = "Hello"
for row in range(5, row_max):
    for col in range(5, col_max):
        worksheet.write(row, col, some_data)


workbook.close()
```

Output Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the XslxWriter [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#constructor):

> **constant_memory**: Reduces the amount of data stored in memory so that large files can be written efficiently:
>
> ```
> workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename, {'constant_memory': True})
> ```
>
> **Note**, in this mode a row of data is written and then discarded when a cell in a new row is added via one of the worksheet `write_()` methods. **Therefore, once this mode is active, data should be written in sequential row order**.

So, trying to overwrite data in previous rows won't work in `constant_memory` mode.

Comment: do you have some recommendations sir inorder to achieve an xlsx manipulation while im in constant memory on? is it better to manipulate on lists before dumping as excel file?

Comment: @iamcoder Yes. That would be the best/only way to do it if you want to use `constant_memory` mode.

Comment: ok sir i will try to give it a shot. many thanks..and will post what will be the results